# Vuetify Treeview with Pagination

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm using the vuetify tree view component to render a large list of items:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/

Is there a way to paginate the loading of the children? I've seen the pagination component but I could not find a way to add pagination to the tree view component, so currently I'm just able to load the first page of the items.

Current tree view implementation:

```
            <v-treeview v-model="selection"
                        @input="on_update_selection"
                        selectionType="leaf"
                        selectable
                        selected-color="blue"
                        :load-children="fetch_children"
                        return-object
                        :items="items">
              <template v-slot:prepend="{ item, open }">
                <v-icon v-if="item.name.endsWith('/')" :data-cy="`import-select-node-${item.name}`">
                  mdi-folder
                </v-icon>
                <v-icon v-else>
                  mdi-file
                </v-icon>
              </template>
            </v-treeview>
```

Any guidance on how to achieve this would be super helpful!

Comment: Can you post the code you've attempted so far? Do you have a working treeview snippet?

Comment: Sure! I added it now to the original question